# How many odd 6 digit numbers can be formed by using the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6 which are divisible by 3?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Well, I have found that we have $$3*6^5$$ odd numbers.
I understand, that if number is divisible by 3, the sum of its digits also should be divisible by 3, but I don't know how to use this...

Comment: what is the lowest $6$ digit odd number?  Is it divisible by $3$? Then every next third odd number is

Comment: @MathLover  111111 and yes it's divisible by 3. I agree. But how do we use that to calculate?

Comment: Can the digits be used only once or more than once each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Big Hint:** Recall that the remainder of any number $n$ when divided by $3$ is equal to the remainder of the sum of the digits of $n$ divided by $3$.

Every number falls in one of three categories:
$$
\mathrm {ABCDE\,1\qquad ABCDE\,3\qquad ABCDE\,5}
$$
Furthermore, each of these three numbers has a different remainder for its sum of digits $\pmod 3$. This is because $\mathrm {A+B+C+D+E}$ is the same for each, but $1,3$ and $5$ have different remainders $\pmod 3$. Therefore, exactly one third of the numbers counted by $3\times 6^5$ will have a remainder of zero.